# PowerShell Get-Content -Raw Not Working

Tags: powershell

I'm running PowerShell v4 and I'm trying to read in a multi-line text file that I want as a single string without line breaks. However, even when I use the -Raw parameter, it is still coming in as an array. It seems like after I put in the -Path the -Raw parameter isn't available anymore because I can't use tab completion for it.

I know there are ways to work around this issue. I'm wondering if anyone has insight into why it isn't working as expected.

Comment: Please provide evidence.

Comment: Just did a test and -raw was available in autocomplete after providing -path on my machine (also PowerShell 4).  Also correctly returned a single string rather than an array when used, can you post an example of the full command you are using that is giving you problems?  as well as the result of either a .gettype() or get-member run on the returned object?

Comment: do you want to get file content line by line ?

Comment: I'm looking to read a file that has multiple lines and have that stored as a single line. I'm finding that my testing now is returning a String, but it's still split into multiple lines.

@AnsgarWiechers Please see the link below.

[pastebin with evidence](http://pastebin.com/Eaawn5ba)

Comment: Umm... your evidence clearly shows that `$activationkey` contains a single string. Reading a file into a single string doesn't magically remove linebreaks, though. You need to do that yourself (``-replace "`r`n"``).

Comment: Thank you, @AnsgarWiechers

I was incorrectly under the impression that the -Raw switch did that from the way [this Q&A](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/06/15/powertip-read-text-file-in-raw-mode-with-powershell/) is worded

Answer (score 0):

Below command works for me:

```
((Get-Content $file) -join "`n") + "`n" | Set-Content -NoNewline $file
```

**Works for PS v5**